# Unable to debug node --inspect with Chrome DevTools

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a node app in Mac M1 Pro using `node --inspect-brk` with Chrome DevTools. This is the output after running the script.

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/f43fcdcb-b0ff-4a2f-8bd4-e60a7ecd817e
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

And when I goto `chrome://inspect`, I'm not seeing any data for inspecting.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved this after configuring `localhost:9229` to `127.0.0.1:9229` in 'Discover network targets'.

[image]

Now its listed under 127.0.0.1

[image]