# nx 15 , nx 16 with nestjs cannot be inspected in Chrome in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: node.js, nestjs, monorepo

I have created a simple [nest](https://nestjs.com/) application with [nx](https://nx.dev/).

By following their official tutorial at: https://nx.dev/recipes/getting-started/set-up-a-new-workspace

- I used `npx create-nx-workspace@15` to create a blank workspace.
- I used these commands to add a nest app into the created workspace:

  - `npm install -D @nx/nest`
  - `nx g @nx/nest:app my-nest-app`
- The commands ran successfully and I could `nx serve my-nest-app` the project:

[image]

- I could open `http://localhost:3000/api` to see the returned json:
  [image]
- However, in the inspect tab of Google chrome browser, I can't inspect the source code:
  [image]

[image]

**NOTE**:

- I have tried with `nx 16` and it was the same
- I have created a minimal reproduction here: https://github.com/redplane/nx-15-debug/tree/main

Does anyone have any solution please ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

After having found this answer: [Unable to debug node --inspect with Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73123870/unable-to-debug-node-inspect-with-chrome-devtools)

I tried the solution which was to change `localhost:9229` to `127.0.0.1:9229` in `Configure...`

It worked fine.

[image]